# Tris and quads in my mesh makes it look messy

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, import, scene

I imported a building scene from SketchUp, so as to render it in blender, but if has too many tris in my mesh, and to unwrap the materials becomes a little too difficult, any solutions for me?[image]

Comment: you can try many things, you could try first "Tris to quads" if it will reduce them and make it better (may not work on whole topology), decimate modifiers are option as well, in worst case scenario you could select vertices in corners and redo it manually... some people may give you more ideas but we need to see what we are dealing with... put some images of that topology

Comment: Hello mickoCG, Ive added a picture..thank you

Comment: Ok I can already see that tris to quads won't probably work, those windows and holes are problem for it.,.. Try to use Decimate modifier with Planar selected and apply it... did it help?

Comment: It didn't work either

Comment: I tried limited dissolve, it works just fine

Comment: Whether you have tris or quads should matter for unwrapping, if you put seams in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately importing meshes from CAD software is always messy.
If the render shading problem is the thing you are struggling, you can try to clear custom split normals data under auto smooth.

It’s pretty time consuming as well to do it on multiple objects, so you can use this code to clear all data on selected objects;

```
import bpy

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

for o in selection:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = o
    bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

I deal with quite a lot of Cad models at work. Most of the time I'm usually on a short time schedule so this is my basic steps for making Cad models not look like shit.

- Unparent/Clear parent, apply rotation and scane, and set origin to geometry.

  - With most of the objects I deal with there is always some weird parenting, scale and placement of object origins, so usually start with this.
  - Setting origin to geometry also helps identify smaller or weird object
- With my data I also get a lot of empties, most of the time it's safe to just delete all those.

  - If there are multiple of them, you can select one, then press Shift + G to Select Grouped, and select by Type. Easy way of selecting all empties in scene to delete them.
- Select everything in scene and enter Edit mode:

  - Select everything in Edit mode
  - Press M and merge by distance, often with Cad models there is a ton of double vertices.
  - ALT + J to convert Tris to Quads, usually does a good job of most faces, but struggles with long narrow faces.
- Back to Object mode, with all objects still selected:

  - Right click in 3D space and set smooth shading
  - Go into the Object Data Properties menu
  - [image]
  - If they have any custom normals, while holding ALT press Clear Custom Split Normals Data
  - Holding ALT when pressing any button or changing any value changes it for all selected objects, so no need for short python scripts.
  - Hold ALT and turn on Auto Smooth under Normals menu
  - Hold ALT and left click the value field for Auto Smooth, type 40 and press Enter, or any other value that works for your objects
- If some objects or surfaces are looking slightly off, just slap a Weighted Normals modifier on it, and check of for Keep Sharp. For hard surface stuff this one is basically black magic.

  - [image]
- And lastly, turn on Statistics in Viewport Overlays to get some easily readable information about objects count and such. Helps figuring out if you have some weird amount of polygons somewhere or not

  - [image]

Hope some of this is of any help.